# Have button style not change when down

Tags: java, libgdx

I'd like the button style to only change when it is checked and not change when it is pressed down, and/or have only the font color change. I'm using the built in Skin function with a .json file, however, that only allows for the up, down, and checked states, along with font color. Is this possibly? If yes, how? If not, then I'll just extend the Button class to add that functionality.

**EDIT**
I have currently just decided to go with a neutral "down" state, but I would still like to know if what I asked is possible.

Comment: Can't you just make the down state be visually identical to the up state?

Comment: @Byte56 Then when I press the button, if it's checked, it'll switch back to the "up" texture on press, not when the button is released. And idk, I'm not the biggest fan of neutral "down" textures, but I may end up doing that.